# Set SPN Service principle name for SQL Server Service account - Best practice

Tags: sql-server, service-accounts

I am looking for guidance on Microsoft recommended best practice regarding setting the SPN for the service account that runs the SQL Server service (MSSSQLSERVER)

When setting up a new server (or changing the service account on an existing server) should I always explicitly set the SPN (even if the server has no linked servers defined) or should it only be set in cases where you experience issues such as a double hop authentication issues when using a linked server?

I want to set the SPN for every service account that runs SQL and our security/AD person only wants to set it for those servers where a linked server is defined.

Is there a downside or security risk in setting SPN if you don't have linked servers.

This question applies to SQL 2012, 2014 and 2016.

I have found a few links that seem to suggest that setting the SPN explicitly should be the best practice  so that Kerberos authentication (SQL's first choice) can be used rather than having to fall back to Windows NT Challenge/Response (NTLM) authentication

Some articles that seem to suggest setting it should always be done

- [FAQS around Kerberos and SQL](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/running-sap-applications-on-the/faqs-around-kerberos-and-sql-server/ba-p/367574)
- [Security Considerations for a SQL Server Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/security-considerations-for-a-sql-server-installation?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Resolving Connectivity Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/resolving-connectivity-errors)
- [SQL Server Kerberos and SPN Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlupdates/sql-server-kerberos-and-spn-quick-reference)

Comment: Has your security admin advised why he prefers NTML over Kerberos, given that [Kerberos is more secure](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_dirservices-mso_o365b/ntlm-vs-kerberos/d8b139bf-6b5a-4a53-9a00-bb75d4e219eb)?

Comment: @HandyD - Admin has not given me a clear answer why he does not want to set the SPN. Thank you for that link! very clear. Can I clarify one thing for my understanding... If we do not explicitly set the SPN, does that definitely mean all authentication will use the less desireable NTML? Thank you

Comment: Some security audits will flag SPNs, and the oft-related finding of Unconstrained Delegation, as a problem to be fixed. They are just looking out to make sure that these settings aren't used where they aren't needed. In my experience so far, the auditors have always been willing to accept the SPNs when they are well documented, even for servers that don't currently have a linked server need. (Getting them to accept Unconstrained Delegation is another matter, and we change it to Constrained wherever we can.)

Comment: @joemcbdc To answer your question, if you don't set the SPN, and your service account does not have permission to write the SPN in AD (likely), then yes it will depend on NTLM for authentication